# Google crawler verification with Prerender not working

Tags: angularjs, apache2, google-search-console, google-crawlers, prerender

I have setup [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io) for SEO of my one of my **Angular** based project. It's hosted on **EC2 Instance** running on **Apache2 server**.

Problem is, when I am doing **Fetch** or **Fetch and Render** on [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters), it not showing expected result.

**Case1:** If I am checking

> http://mywebsite/something

It is fetching just **index.html** file

**Case2:** If I am checking

> http://mywebsite/?_escaped_fragment_=/something

It is showing this: [image]

Is there a way to verify and to show that crawler is actually crawling my website content or not. Specifically which content crawler actually getting.

Comment: It looks like you have a 302 redirect pointing to service.prerender.io/yourURL which is incorrect. You want your middleware to do a proxy, not a redirect. If you are using html5 push state, you'll want `http://mywebsite/something` to be accessed like `http://mywebsite/something?_escaped_fragment_=` and as long as you have the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag in the `<head>` of your page then Google will automatically crawl with the `?_escaped_fragment_=` parameter. Fetch as Google has an issue where they don't automatically check for the fragment meta tag even though Googlebot does

Comment: I have the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag in the <head> of  my index.html page. And my .htaccess file code has 
  **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

  # Proxy the request
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]**

Then, is crawler being redirected from http://mywebsite/something to the cached raw html.? @Prerender.io

Comment: See here for the correct configuration: https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354. You should use [P] instead of [R=302]. Doing a redirect tells Google that you want them to send users to service.prerender.io which is very bad. You want to do a proxy [P] in order for Google to receive the response from your actual URL and send users to your URL.